# Initialization of the Python runtime is stopped by OS error from Dart package python_ffi

Tags: python, dart, speech-recognition, ffi

To explain my situation, I'm looking to use voice recognition inside of my Flutter program on a windows desktop. Since I couldn't find any libraries for this for Dart, I started to look at some FFIs. Now I'm using the python module [SpeechRecognition](https://pypi.org/project/SpeechRecognition/) (specifically Openai Whisper) and using the package [python_ffi](https://pub.dev/packages/python_ffi) to use this python runtime in Dart, and get the interpreted text into my Flutter program.

I have tried to initialize the python runtime following [this example](https://github.com/IVLIVS-III/dart_python_ffi/#initializing-the-python-runtime). When this is called I get an OS error from "await PythonFfi.instance.initialize();" (Line 6), specifically the error:

```
Exception has occurred.
PathAccessException (PathAccessException: Cannot delete file, path = 'C:\Users\Gebruiker\AppData\Roaming\com.example\speech_recognition_test/python_ffi/lib/python3.11.zip' (OS Error: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
, errno = 32))
```

To give my interpretation of what's happening:
Dart is making a Python3.11.zip file, and this is still in use for some odd reason and is trying to delete it for some odd reason.
So basically, I don't have the slightest clue on what's going on.

The only thing I could have thought that would work is wait until the file was no longer in use, and put a delay of 2 minutes before the "await PythonFfi.instance.initialize();" line. This obviously ended up in no new results.

Here is my main.dart file, since it seems to be the only thing of relevance:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:python_ffi/python_ffi.dart';

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await PythonFfi.instance.initialize();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Speech Recognition Test',
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(
            seedColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 85, 58, 183)),
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      home: Material(
        child: RecorderWidget(
          key: key,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class RecorderWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const RecorderWidget({
    super.key,
  });

  @override
  State<RecorderWidget> createState() => _RecorderWidgetState();
}

class _RecorderWidgetState extends State<RecorderWidget> {
  bool _isActivated = false;
  Color color = Colors.red;

  void _toggleActivation() {
    setState(() {
      if (_isActivated) {
        color = Colors.red;
        _isActivated = false;
      } else {
        color = Colors.green;
        _isActivated = true;
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        const SizedBox(
          height: 60,
        ),
        Row(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          children: [
            Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10), color: color),
              height: 20,
              width: 20,
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              width: 40,
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: _toggleActivation,
              child: const Icon(Icons.mic),
            )
          ],
        ),
        const SizedBox(
          height: 40,
        ),
        const Text(
          "Balls in the walls.",
          style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 20),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Right now, I'm still in a very experimental stage of testing this out. So if you notice anything that's wrong, please do tell. All kinds of help would be greatly appreciated!